# facebook contacts from android phonebook

Tags: android, android-contacts

Need to get all facebook contacts from android phonebook. *"People"* shows facebook contacts... Use resolver  to get all contacts

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);
```

and take from it facebook contacts, but `Cursor` doesn't return facebook contacts in general content. Will be glad to any proposals.